# Is Ethereum Alarm Clock still alive and well?

Tags: timers, alarm

Lots of questions here reference [Ethereum Alarm Clock](http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/) as a way to schedule events.  It seems to my eye to no longer be operative.  Is that the case, or am I mistaken?  If it's isn't operative, is there another service that offers similar scheduling functionality?

Comment: I think it is still alive while there is new comits https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-alarm-clock/commits/master. I think this question should be posted on their github.

Comment: The contract seems to be idle for a while now. https://etherscan.io/address/0x6c8f2a135f6ed072de4503bd7c4999a1a17f824b

Comment: Asked and answered at the repo - https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-alarm-clock/issues/81

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Ethereum Alarm Clock is alive and well. It's on mainnet. **In the first few months it transferred more than 1000 ETH safely.** It has also been audited by BokkyPooBah.

There's also new page: https://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/.

Ethereum Alarm Clock is also integrated as `Send Later` button in MyCrypto. [Here's tutorial how it works.](https://chronologic.network/schedule)

Using [MyCrypto](https://www.mycrypto.com/) or [Chronos DAPP](https://app.chronologic.network) you can also easily transfer ERC20 tokens.

Also support for transferring ERC721 (aka Cryptocollectibles aka NFT) has been added to [EAC Chronos DAPP](https://app.chronologic.network), so you can transfer CryptoKitties and other collectibles.

Answer (score 2):

Based on their gitter, no. The service is currently inactive.
https://gitter.im/pipermerriam/ethereum-alarm-clock. Best to get in touch with https://github.com/pipermerriam/ to check on a reboot schedule.

Comment: This answer is out of date. Ethereum Alarm Clock is well.

Answer (score 2):

I think they're reviving it. The new gitter is https://gitter.im/ethereum-alarm-clock/ethereum-alarm-clock.